# How to protect usb ports in active directory with password?

Tags: windows, active-directory, passwords, usb

I want to protect the usb ports on all computers in the network with password through active directory. Not just to disable them. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Security model of Windows based on Access Token. So user account allows or denies access to any protected Active Directory's objects through the Access Token. User get Access Token after successful login from Domain Controller. And continue works with kerberous tickets. Another worlds user get Active Directory's allowed scope in login time.

You can use Group Policy for set scopes users who can used any USB devices.

If you want more capabilities you can try third part software like DeviceLock for example.

Good look.